# Why does a simple for loop work in the onCreate method but not in the MainActivity class?

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

I am learning Android and I came across an anomalous behavior of a loop in the Main Activity class in Android. Consider the following piece of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int game_board[][] = new int[3][3];    
    int limit = 3;
    for(int row = 0; row < limit; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < limit; column++){
            game_board[row][column] = -1;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(int row = 0; row < limit; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < limit; column++){
                game_board[row][column] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The for loop in MainActivity class is giving me a list of compile time errors (All syntaxual), for eg: **error: ')' expected, error: ';' expected** for the outer `row` for loop. But the same nested for loop is not raising any errors in the onCreate method.

What's the reason for this to happen? Is it something to do with the UI thread or just a basic concept in general? (Also restarted Android Studio but still got the same issues). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the UI thread - you simply can't put a block of code directly inside a class. It must reside in a method, constructor or initializer block.

Comment: @RishabParmar yes - those are called [members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: Darn it! I deleted my own comment by mistake. Anyways, for anyone referring this thread, the question I asked in this comment was that can we initialize/ declare variables outside a method in a class, to which you can refer to the above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some answers is well explained. Basically you can just put method inside a class it self, it should be placed inside a method, like you mention, inside `onCreate`

And I think there is some special case where you do want your method not depend on some other method(like `onCreate`). This time you can consider making you method to `static`.

`static` means this method is register once this class is made, and it won't depend on other child method replying on a real instance of the class.

Take your code as example, first wrap your loop inside a static annotated method:

```java
public static void doForLoop() {
    int game_board[][] = new int[3][3];    
    int limit = 3;
    for(int row = 0; row < limit; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < limit; column++){
            game_board[row][column] = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call this `doForLoop` method just inside the class itself.

You can learn more about `static` method and `static variable` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write code in a class; code must be placed in a method.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     int game_board[][] = new int[3][3];   

     void name_void(){ 
            int limit = 3;
            for(int row = 0; row < limit; row++){
                for(int column = 0; column < limit; column++){
                    game_board[row][column] = -1;
                }
               }
              }

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                name_void();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `You cannot write code in a class` this doesn't make sense, you CAN write code in a class, just not this type of code :)